# Ciruit Board with traces on top and bottom?

Tags: pcb, circuit-design

I was looking at re-making a Circuit board. The Circuit board I have has the same exact traces on top and bottom. I cant figure out why this would be done. Any one have any idea why you would have the same layout for traces on top and bottom side?

Thanks
GM

EDIT
Pretty much its a back plane that takes a 50 pin ribbon cable from the back side of the board to a 65 pin quick connect to front side of board. with the other 15 pins, they go to other connectors that are connected to DMM , Spec Anlizer , o scope ect..

[image]

Comment: Is it using thru-hole or surface mount components?

Comment: Quite some, but for your specific case, photos might come in handy to tell

Comment: It's highly uncomon and if you are paying for two sided PCBs, there are better design practices. Probably someone found a quick way to increase copper area, mechanical stability or just an error by the PCB manufacturer.

Comment: its thru-hole ,  and i have 2 of these boards and orginal layout drawings. IT was done on purpose.

Comment: So each component pin is connected to two traces?

Comment: @EugeneSh. yes top and bottom , both traces ran same way to to say point.   So pin 1 goes to pin 2 via two traces one on top and one on bottom. same exact routeing path

Comment: Sounds strange. It could be a weird and not a best way of increasing the current capacity of the traces...

Comment: @EugeneSh. the guy that design this board was a very smart guy he has passed away years ago so i cant ask him why.  Only thing i could think of was reliability ? in case one of the traces gets messed up? But before making a new one.. i wanted to see if there was any reason i dont know of to do this.

Comment: I don't know about the application. but this way it will just add unnecessary ground (and other signal) loops, increase (much) the capacitance of the lines. Sounds like a very bad design. smart guys are making mistakes too.

Comment: Check out of this "smart guy" design was done without plated through holes. Using the same artwork design on the top and bottom of a through hole design is sometimes a method to keep from needing to have plated through holes. Hack at best for any reasonable board production volume.

Comment: @EugeneSh. added image if it helps .   I did check and the thru-holes are plated.

Comment: That picture looks like it's only the nets, without showing any traces at all...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For lower volume PC boards manufactured in the U.S. or Canada, it is usually much, much cheaper to just use a board house' cheapest and most standard setup: 2 layers, 0.0625" thick FR4 board, green soldermask, standard drill sizes, etc. This way, they don't have to change the work flow. If that is the case, then you get the bottom side for "free" so you might as well use it to decrease resistance and improve reliability.

Duplicating the top layer is also a no-brainer. Don't bother laying out the bottom layer. Just copy the top gerber file and rename it as the bottom gerber file. Any text will read backwards though :)

You can use a text merge program (used by SW dudes) to see if there is any difference between the top and bottom gerber files. They are simple text files. If exactly the same, this is probably what the previous engineer did.

Comment: I think the decrease resistance along with , getting it for "free" may be the reason. This board is used in a machine that 75% of time just checks resistance

Answer (score 1):

PCBs come with different weight copper (that is, [how thick the copper is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printed_circuit_board#Copper_thickness)).  Hardware designers are sensitive to [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_of_materials) cost.  Especially on high run PCBs.  It may have been that the cost of a light weight double sided copper board was lower than a heavy weight single sided copper board.

Another possibility, if the traces are offset by one from the top to the bottom, it may be a way of adding shielding.  It is common to interleave ribbon cable signal with ground.  If this was done here for this back plane, that would mean a ground trace would be above (or below) and to the left and right of each signal trace.

Answer (score 0):

Ideas that spring to mind are: (a) to increase the current capability with the thin tracks you need between these connectors; (b) to let you put the board in backwards and solder the through-hole connectors to the other side.

Answer (score 0):

When a PCB has significantly more copper on one side than the other, the board can actually warp or bend. Copper foil and fiberglass have different temperature coefficient of expansion, and with an asymmetrical layer stack the board will warp. It's more of a problem with large boards or very thin boards (like 0.031" thick instead of the usual 0.62"). The warping problem can be addressed by mounting board stiffeners, but these add cost. Duplicating layer 1 to layer 2 prevents the board from warping, by keeping the internal stresses symmetrical.